# C++ polymorphism and template class

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

I have a class of the form:

```
  template redblacknode<T>
```

Which is stored in a tree of the form:

```
  template redblacktree<redblacknode<T> >
```

For a particular tree I want the nodes to both store the same information (two different longs) but to be indexed on the different values.

I am initialising the nodes like this:

```
PageRecord addPR = PageRecord(pageNumber, -1);
findNode = new redblackNode<PageRecord>(addPR);
```

Can I get polymorphic behaviour out of this (by overloading the == and < operators) even though I am not plugging a pointer into the node?

Comment: findNode is a pointer isn't it?

Comment: Are you sure you want to have your tree templatized by your node type? Wouldn't you rather define your `redblacktree<T>` so that the `T` is the same `T` as in `redblacknode<T>`?

Comment: I wrote the tree code some years ago and am reusing it so refactoring it probably not worth it, but I am interested your suggestion: I suppose I could just have give the nodes an interface and only templatised them.

Comment: jia suggestion is more like this : have template redblacktree<T> in your code ; if you need the redblacknode, you can have redblacknode<T> (like redblacknode<T> getNode(TreeIndex index);). No need to create a common interface.

Answer (score 1):

You can use static polymorphism but a simpler way can be:

```
template<typename T>
class redblacknode
{
public:
    redblacknode(T t) : m_t(t) {}
    T getT() const { return m_t; }
private:
    T m_t;
};

template<typename T> inline
bool operator< (const redblacknode<T>& lhs, const redblacknode<T>& rhs) {   return  lhs.getT() < rhs.getT();    }
```

in main.cpp :

```
redblacknode<int> a(1);
redblacknode<int> b(2);
redblacknode<int>* c = new  redblacknode<int>(3);

qDebug() << (b < a); // print false
qDebug() << (b < *c); // print true
```

After, if you want dynamic polymorphism (basically, virtual functions + pointers), it depends on your template redblacknode definition (you'll need a super class, see CRTP).

Edit: I assume your pointer type is redblackNode*

Edit2: I changed a bit my code to reflect yours.

Comment: I am probably being a bit stupid here, but where's the polymorphism? They're all ints aren't they?

Comment: Indeed, I didn't use static polymorphism - only classical template, as (if I understood correctly your question), you may not need static polymorphism. Static polymorhism would more like this : template< class Derived >
class Base {};
 
class Derived1: public Base< Derived1 > {};
 
class Derived2 : public Base< Derived2 > {}; In this case, what is the use of PageRecord?

Comment: I suggest you check http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/05/17/the-curiously-recurring-template-pattern-in-c ; static polymorphism will be needed if you want to compare 2 PageRecord using PageRecord interface; but if you need only redblacknode<PageRecord> interface to compare them, no need for it.